# strstr() to search two different strings in the same line

Tags: c, string, strstr

I am trying to search two different strings in a line using strstr.

```
sBuffer = "This is app test"
s1= strstr (sBuffer, "This");
s2= strstr (sBuffer, "test");
printf("%s\n", s1); //prints - This is app test 
printf("%s\n", s2); //prints - test
if (s1 && s2)
    //do something
```

Expected output for s1 should be the string `"This"` but it is printing the entire string for s1.

s2 however is printed correctly.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Although all the answers are correct (upvoted all answers), I am accepting dasblinkenlight's answer. This is because I realize checking the boolean condition as shown below would suffice my requirement. Thanks for all the answers.

```
if ( (strstr (sBuffer, "This")) && (strstr (sBuffer, "test")) )
        //do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `strstr` is the pointer to the original, unmodified, string at the point of the match. The reason why the second call displays `test` is a coincidence: `test` simply happens to be at the end of the searched string. Had the `sBuffer` been `"This is app test of strstr"`, the output for the second call would be `test of strstr`, not simply `test`.

To fix this, you can change your program like this:

```
printf("%s\n", s1 ? "This" : "");
printf("%s\n", s2 ? "test" : "");
```

The reason this works is that you know that the only case when `strstr` would return a non-null pointer is when it finds the exact match to what you've been searching for. If all you need is a boolean "found/not found" flag, you can simply test `s1` and `s2` for `NULL`. You are using this trick already in your final `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

You're not understanding what the function does.

It gives you the address in `sBuffer` ("the haystack") where the search string ("the needle") has been found. It doesn't *modify* the haystack string, so it won't terminate the sub-string.

You have:

```
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
sBuffer: | T | h | i | s |   | i | s |  | a | p | p |   | t | e | s | t | \0 |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
           ^                                              ^
           |                                              |
           |                                              |
  strstr(sBuffer, "Test")                        strstr(sBuffer, "test")
```

As you can see, `strstr(sBuffer, "Test")` will simply return `sBuffer`, which of course still contains the rest of the characters, it's the same memory buffer.

If you need to extract the sub-string that you found, you must do so yourself. A suitable function to use is `strlcpy()` if you have it, else `strncpy()` will work since you know the exact length of the data to copy.

Comment: any clue on how to get the expected output I am looking for?

Comment: @user32262 `memcpy(some_buffer, retval_of_strstr, strlen(needle))` then NUL-terminate `some_buffer`.

Comment: So which one is better to use in this case? strncpy() or memcpy()?

Answer (score 1):

`strstr()` returns a pointer to the first character of the substring it found. It doesn't NUL-terminate the string after the searched substring, this is the expected and correct behavior.

As to the solution: if you have a non-`const` string, you can simply modify it so that it's NUL-terminated at the correct position (but then beware of the modifications you made). If not, then make a copy of the substring.

```
const char *haystack = "abcd efgh ijkl";
const char *needle   = "efgh";

const char *p = strstr(haystack, needle);
if (p) {
    size_t l = strlen(needle);
    char buf[l + 1];
    memcpy(buf, p, l);
    buf[l] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```